# Flutter upload file to s3 - using only dart code

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, file-upload, amazon-cognito, image-upload

I'm trying to upload an audio file to s3. It seems like there is no straightforward approach. I found a few libraries.

1. https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart
   This one is incompatible with the latest dart version and there is no update information also. https://github.com/jonsaw/amazon-cognito-identity-dart/issues/27 So I couldn't use it.
2. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_aws_s3_client - Got deprecated
3. https://pub.dev/packages/aws_s3
4. https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart
5. https://pub.dev/packages/simple_s3-

3, 4, 5, and a few more libraries using AWS Cognito pool ID for authentication, But I found that to use the Cognito pool ID, our app user authentication should be done with this service. But In our app, authentication has already been created using the JWT token. So I couldn't AWS Cognito service. But still not sure completely as we can use Cognito pool ID with JWT token authentication.

Moreover, we can do it using the native code of iOS and Android and connect it using the flutter channel. But It seems too expensive in terms of time and complexity.

We have another way that we can send the media file to our backend server and from the server-side, we can upload it to the S3 bucket.

But I'm trying to figure out a way to do this from the frontend side itself.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [amazon_cognito_upload](https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_upload)  package to upload any file.
This package is super simple to use.

Example :

```
void uploadFile() {

AWSWebClient.uploadFile(
    s3UploadUrl: '', //s3 bucket url like : https://yourbucketname.s3.region.amazonaws.com/
    s3SecretKey: '',
    s3Region: '',
    s3AccessKey: '',
    s3BucketName: '',
    folderName: '', //This will auto generate folder in s3 bucket
    fileName: '',  // add unique file name with extension like: "10540124.jpg" 
    fileBytes: '', //This will take file as Uint8List bytes
  );
}
```